# Percentages of variance in Y explained by X_1,..X_n - adds up to 1?

Tags: regression, r-squared

Assume the following common scenario: we have a dependent variable Y, which we regress against a number of explanatory variables, X_1, X_2, .. , X_n. Each of these regressors explains a certain percentage of the variance in Y, as given by the square of the respective R statistics, R_1, R_2, .. R_n.

What I would expect is that the sum of these explained variances would always be smaller than 100%, i.e. that they never really add up to 1, but that the sum can approach this limit as the number of regressors (n) increases.

Instead, what seems to happen is that the sum of explained variances actually exceeds 1. My questions are: (1) when this happens, is it an indication that the regressors overlap in terms of their explanatory power (i.e. they are not independent); and (2) is it ever the case (when?) that this sum actually reaches (or very closely approaches) 1, assuming independent regressors?

Comment: Probably they are correlated so they're explaining the "same" variation when taken separately.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still unconvinved with regards to my question about them adding up to 1.

Comment: Consider extreme examples, like where you have two predictors $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are *perfectly* correlated.  Then the individual regressions have the same $R^2$ and their sum will exceed one whenever $R^2 > 1/2$.  There's really no reason why the sum needs to be less than one as situations like this show.